# how to execute google maps event "bounds_changed" only once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I tell the google map event "bounds_change" to only work when the map is initially loaded, and not after user change?

Comment: `bounds_change` is designed to handle viewport changes which probably gets fired multiple times during the app's lifetime. So why you want to use this event to handle loaded event?

Comment: I have two types of loading of maps.  The first load calls a specific function, while the movement later on (by the user) calls a different function.  I am trying to use the get_bounds() function, but the map requires to finish bounding first.  So, I need to put in a listener to execute the first function upon startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapsEventListener)

> addListenerOnce(instance:Object, eventName:string, handler:function(?))
>   Return Value:  MapsEventListener
>   Like addListener, but the handler removes itself after handling the first event.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'bounds_changed', function() {});
```