# Get features present in map viewport from geoJSON

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I need to add markers on the map for the data that I have.

Out of the thought process, I went through `map.data.loadGeoJson('google.json');` with which I will be able to have custom data attached to the map. Now, there is a requirement that I need to show properties of the features present in the map viewport. I cannot loop through all the items and check for `.contains()`, I have a huge data. Is there default google way to get the properties of the features present in the map viewport?

Comment: Can you explain with small example

Comment: Depending on how "huge" is your data this may help:
http://nickjohnson.com/b/google-maps-v3-how-to-quickly-add-many-markers

If the size of you json file is several Mb, then you should consider calling the data from a database like MySQL from PHP via AJAX, sending the map bounds every time you have a 'bounds_changed' event and retrieving only the visible information. You will also have to adapt your query to the zoom not to crash your site, using any clustering algorithm.

If this approach works for you, let me know and I can give you some more details. I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

### I like using [TurfJS](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf) for tasks like these. I've tested it w/ 1M points and it works more quickly than one'd expect.

---

**Pseudocode**

1. load your GeoJSON once and initialize it as a turf feature collection
2. transform your map viewport's bounds into a GeoJSON polygon
3. run the `pointsWithinPolygon` function
4. pass the resulting feature collection onto the map data layer using [`addGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.addGeoJson)
5. rinse & repeat within a [throttled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30603010/8160318) `bounds_changed` event

---

**Actual Code**

```
/*
 You'd load your own geojson like so:
 const points = turf.featureCollection(geojsonObject.features)
*/

// random 1M points as a demo
const points = turf.randomPoint(1e6, {
    bbox: [-180, -90, 180, 90]
});

const {
    west,
    south,
    east,
    north
} = map.getBounds().toJSON();

// extent in minX, minY, maxX, maxY order
const viewport_as_polygon = turf.bboxPolygon([west, south, east, north])


const points_within = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, viewport_as_polygon)
```

---

Note: Since none of this interacts with the DOM until you call `addGeoJSON`, it's gonna be faster than for instance generating markers for each feature and then hiding/modifying the transparency of those that are outside of the viewport.